# How to prevent Asus Super Hybrid Engine dial from showing up on boot in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I am setting up an Asus ET2011 for some friends. It ships with a feature that Asus calls Super Hybrid Engine that saves power when the machine's full performance isn't needed (which is just about always in this case).

My problem is that S.H.E. includes a very garish speed dial widget that float on top of windows and obscures around 15% of the screen. You can minimise it to the system tray via a right click menu, but it reappears when you reboot.

I have found instructions (by Googling around) on how to disable S.H.E altogether, but that's not the goal here.
I want to get rid of the dial, not S.H.E itself.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else is looking for the solution to this question, I just figured out that if you right-click on the widget and choose "Start at Minimum Mode", it defaults to being minimized to the tray.

Answer (score 0):

If the management application is seperate from S.H.E, you could probably temporarily disable it using [autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902) or msconfig

Comment: As far as I can tell, it's not :(